# need the stratum url for zpool for sha-256

Tags: mining-pools

I'd like to use [Zpool](http://zpool.ca/) with my S9. I need the stratum URL to use for sha-256.

They give examples for X11 and Scrypt.

For example I could use the following:

```
Bitmain D3 Settings:
URL: x11.mine.zpool.ca:3533#xnsub
Worker: XkurctD63DTsfx7hEuHqS3dC9wQmu4qFtN
Password: c=dash,d=92

Bitmain L3+ Settings:
URL: scrypt.mine.zpool.ca:3433#xnsub
Worker: LeDKeCAUVAxhSk1L3XDN2EV1b7dHVjTcqz
Password: c=ltc,d=128000
```

I guess my issues are:

- is the algo for the url sha256 or sha-256
- what is the port to use at the end of the url? (looks like different ones based on algo)
- what is #xnsub ? Is it needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the algo for the url sha256 or sha-256

The URL should be `sha256.mine.zpool.ca`.

> what is the port to use at the end of the url? (looks like different ones based on algo)

For sha256 you should use port `3333`.

> what is #xnsub ? Is it needed?

It turns on extraNonce, which gives your miner extra room to work.